# Why does nmap think my computer has two IP addresses?

Tags: windows-7, ip, ip-address, nmap, ipconfig

Nmap seems to think my computer has two IP addresses.
When I run `ipconfig`, I get

```
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
 Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::****:****:****:****%12
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.22
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
```

Yet when I run `nmap -p80 192.168.2.0/24`, I get

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.1
Host is up (0.0088s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
MAC Address: A0:8E:3A:F3:67:28 (Unknown)


Skipping SYN Stealth Scan against 192.168.2.15 because Windows does not support
scanning your own machine (localhost) this way.
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.15
Host is up.
PORT   STATE   SERVICE
80/tcp unknown http

Skipping SYN Stealth Scan against 192.168.2.22 because Windows does not support
scanning your own machine (localhost) this way.
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.22
Host is up.
PORT   STATE   SERVICE
80/tcp unknown http
```

This seems to imply that my computer has two IP addresses - `192.168.2.15` and `192.168.2.22` ?
How can that be ?

Comment: Have you tried to ping `192.168.2.15`?

Comment: Yes I get 4 replies

Comment: So those 2 addresses are running on your PC. Try to put  `192.168.2.15` on your browser, does it lead to something?

Comment: No it goes to the Chrome `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` page

Comment: What is the output of `ipconfig /all`?

Comment: Ahhh does it make sense that my VPN (NordVPN) is responsible for that extra IP address ?

Comment: @CodyBugstein Yes. Do you see `TAP-Windows adapter` among your network adapters?

Comment: You can check by connecting to VPN, type ```ncpa.cpl``` in run, right click on your VPN adapter and click on status. You can find the IP there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue was my NordVPN running

Thanks to the commenters for their help